# getJSON from Wikipedia API returning empty array

Tags: jquery, api, getjson, wikipedia

[code from CodePen](http://codepen.io/rcidaleassumpo/pen/bVaYzy)

```
var link = "http://cors.io/?u=https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=dog&format=json"

$.getJSON(link).done(function(data){
  $("#result").append("Hello World");
  console.log(data);
});
```

Hello everyone, i tried to find the answer for this question, and unfortunately I couldn't.. 
I think the solution it might be basic, but I can't figure out, and I don't even know how to think through this situation to find an answer by myself. 
So basically what I want is to call for the wikipedia api and get back the content. When I put the link into the browser, it gives me back nicely the result, but when I tried to use CodePen, I got stuck. It gives me back something, but and empty array. 
What am I missing.. Thanks

To solve the problem, instead of using the cors.io I used the solution made by @Bergi, calling for jsonp with the plain link. 
Thank you!

Comment: CORS is not present?

Comment: The Wikipedia API call by itself gives me the result, but requesting it through http://cors.io gives `["",[],[],[]]`

Comment: whenever I call without using the cors.io I receive no access controll cross origin header

Comment: @RenanCidale: Just use JSONP.

Comment: I tried that aswell by adding &callback=? and nothing happens, I mean, not even the Hello World is shown at the screen, which means that something was blocking the call .. I believe..